# Color Display are not right

Tags: color

I am Robert and have been using macbook Pro for quite sometime. However the color display had been a problem from the time of purchase. I tried different ways to calibrate but to no avail. 
Finally tried Colorsync Utility option for repair and first aid. It indicated that the system has 4 bad profiles which the automatic first aid did not fix.
The bad profiles are;

Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/RedBlueYellow.icc

Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/smokey.icc

Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/TealMagenta.icc

Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/TotalLinkPreview.icc

I have been regularly updating the OS and now am on Yosemite...

Could someone help me to set it right please.

Answer (score 1):

As you know those are Adobe ICC profiles, thus made by Abode to support they suite of Graphics products.

Some ICC's are specific to a Adobe product you are using and come as part of the installation package.

To find those ICC profiles, look in the original installation package.

In some cases you might see a problem where the ColorSync Utility claims a profile cannot be fixed.

ColorSync utility - Verify and Repair:

In cases where the ColorSync fails to repair a ICC profile, you will need to go to the profile in the Finder, get information on it, and ensure your username is added in the Sharing & Permissions section with both Read and Write privileges.

You can also use Terminal to find them.

```
find /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/ -name "*.icc" -exec sips --verify {} \;
```

When done, re-run the repair routine, and hopefully that will allow the profile to be fixed.

Or again use Terminal to try to Repair them:

```
find /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/ -name "*.icc" -exec sips --repair {} \;
```

Here is some [more reading material](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WSBB0A8512-8151-408c-9F79-4A9E9E3BA84C.html).

Comment: the link provided to download the profiles do not assist in downloading for mac. May be it is of window link and not of Mac.

Comment: Which one (or all) do you use? Creative Suite® 3, Illustrator® CS3, InDesign® CS3, or Photoshop® CS3

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest in assisting me. Unfortunate that I could not get back immediately to respond to your question. I use all but CS6... not CS3. Thank you